# The Admin page isn't showing in the sidebar of the dashboard

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, wp-admin

I added this class to my plugin directory, but when I refresh my dashboard, the admin page doesn't show up and I do not get any errors. Am I doing something wrong in the `__construct()` method?

```
class AA_Admin_Page {

    /**
     * Title of the page.
     */
    public $page_title;

    /**
     * Text to be used for the menu.
     */
    public $menu_title;

    /** 
     * Unique slug for the menu page. 
     */
    public $slug;

    function __construct() {
        $this->$page_title  = __( 'AA Plugin Page', 'AA-plugin' );
        $this->$menu_title  = __( 'AA Plugin Page', 'AA-plugin' );
        $this->slug         = 'aa_admin_page';

        $this->render_page();
    }

    public function render_page() {
        add_action( 'admin_init', [ $this, 'aa_admin_page' ] );
    }

    public function aa_admin_page() {
        add_menu_page(
            $this->$page_title,
            $this->$menu_title,
            'manage_options',
            $this->$slug,
            [ $this, 'admin_page_callback' ],
        );
    }

    public function admin_page_callback() {
        echo "This page works!";
    }
}
new AA_Admin_Page();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `add_action( 'admin_init', [ $this, 'aa_admin_page' ] );`

Try: `add_action( 'admin_menu', [ $this, 'aa_admin_page' ] );`

Edit: And all instances of `$this->$foo` should be `$this->foo`

Comment: Nope, still not showing up :(

Comment: See edited answer.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you!